# Improving run time of simple query

Tags: python, django, database-design

Gurus:

I have a very simple data model relating two different kinds of `User`s via an `Interaction`:

```
# myapp/models.py
class C1(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class C2(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Interaction(models.Model):
 c1 = models.ForeignKey(C1)
 c2 = models.ForeignKey(C2)
 date = models.DateField()
```

So, an `Interaction` has a `User` of class `C1`, a `User` of class `C2`, and a date (in addition to the primary key, automatically an integer); a given pair of users can have many `Interaction`s.

I populated the database with 2000 random `User`s (1000 each class), and when I query the `Interaction` the run time is too slow (about three seconds - unacceptable in production environment).

Is there something I can do to improve the run time of this search? Should I define the `Interaction` differently?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact query you are running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like to store additional information related to your users, Django provides a method to specify a site-specific related model -- termed a "user profile" -- for this purpose.

To make use of this feature, define a model with fields for the additional information you'd like to store, or additional methods you'd like to have available, and also add a OneToOneField from your model to the User model. This will ensure only one instance of your model can be created for each User. For example:

```
# settings.py
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'myapp.UserProfile'

# myapp/models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    CLASS_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Yellow User'),
        (1, 'Green User'),
    )
    user_class = models.IntegerField(choices=CLASS_CHOICES)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Interaction(models.Model):
    u1 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='u1s')
    u2 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='u2s')
    date = models.DateField()
```

Creating a new model and associated table for each User class seems not like good design.

Comment: Yeah, I figured creating two entirely different classes based on User might not be the best idea... I will try your approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have used foreign keys to associate `C1, C2` with `Users`, and called this a **one-to-many relationship**. However, the relationship between `Interaction` `C1, C2` is not one-to-many because one `Interaction` can be associated with many `Users`, and one `User` can also have many `Interactions` associated with it. This is called a **many-to-many relationship**, and is represented in Django models using `models.ManyToManyField`.

So try changing your `models.py` file to -

```
class Interaction(models.Model):
    ic1 = models.ManyToManyField(C1)
    ic2 = models.ManyToManyField(C2)
    date= models.DateField()
```

See if this helps...

Comment: Can't see how that's right at all. Surely the relationship between C1 and C2 is the many-to-many, and Interaction is the through table for that relationship?

Comment: but isn't this a better way to represent this db relationship? Agreed, that I am not sure about performance...